# Can I use fieldsets and role="group" together on same form element section

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, section508

I have been researching this issue for a 508 accessibility assignment and from the sounds of it using fieldsets and legends are an alternative to using role="group", role="radiogroup", etc. and vice versa. Is this correct or should I be using both elements in tandem with one another? So for instance would the following code be correct?

```
<fieldset>
                <legend class="h3">Which products interest you?</legend>
                <div class="controls" role="group">
                    <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
                    <input class="checkbox-btn-control" id="medical-non-medicare" type="checkbox" name="product1" value="Medical (not eligible for Medicare)" aria-label="Medical (not eligible for Medicare)">
                    <label for="medical-non-medicare">Medical (not eligible for Medicare)</label>
                    <input class="checkbox-btn-control" id="dental" type="checkbox" name="product2" value="dental" id="Dental">
                    <label for="dental">Dental</label>
                    <input class="checkbox-btn-control" id="medicare-advantage" type="checkbox" name="product3" value="Medicare Advantage" aria-label="Medicare Advantage">
                    <label for="long-term-care">Medicare Advantage</label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#elementdef-fieldset), default aria role for `fieldset` is "group"

So you may define the `role` with the value "group" on a `fieldset` (which is redundant and unnecessary but permitted).

What you can't do is defining another value that "group" on the `role` attribute for `fieldset` elements

In your example, the problem is that you'll have two different elements with the `role=group` value (`fieldset` and `div`). I would say that the inner one may have precedence and prevent your screenreader from accessing the `legend` element.